# Type alphanumeric keys in a Credit Card Format

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my current React appication, I have an alpha numeric 13 digit key which I would like to type and paste in a credit card format on another screen i.e first 3 boxes should contain 3 digits each and the fourth box should contain 4 digits.
For example- box1 box2 box3 box4

The focus should move to next box at first digit once the first box has all 3 digits.

I am using react text mask for this.

```
handleFocus = () =>{
    let val = document.akBox.first.value.length+1;
    if (val <= 3)
    {
      document.akBox.first.focus()
    }
    else
      {
        document.akBox.second.focus()
      }
    }

<form name='akBox'>
    <div className="col-md-1" onKeyUp={this.handleFocus}>
         <MaskedInput name= "first" mask={[/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/, /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/, /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/]}/> 
    </div>
    <div className="col-md-1"  >
        <MaskedInput  name= "second" mask={[/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/, /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/, /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/]}/> 
    </div>
    <div className="col-md-1">
        <MaskedInput name="third" mask={[/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/, /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/, /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/]} /> 
    </div>
    <div className="col-md-1">
         <MaskedInput name="fourth" mask={[/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/, /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/, /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/,/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/]} /> 
    </div>
 </form>
```

I am able to achieve the solution but the problem with react text mask is I am not able to move the focus to next boxes and paste the 13 digit keys by splitting in 3-3-3-4 format. I am learning react and would like to know how can I make this accept alphabets as well. Help much appreciated!

Comment: It might be worth experimenting with [React Input Mask](https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask/tree/master/react#readme) which supports other characters than just numbers.

Comment: This was amazing.It worked!!

Comment: @Tholle I am putting the combination of 4 digits in 4 different divs and trying to move the focus automatically to next div once 4th digit is entered.Please see me updated code.Its not however changing the focus to next div.